# when do you use getGraphObject and getGraphEdge

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm working on a php based site and integrating some facebook sdk into it to get some basic user information. One thing I've been running into is, when I make a request to the graph, how do I know if I should be using getGraphObject or getGraphEdge? I'm not seeing anything intuitive yet to tell me that.

I'm running the php-sdk4 -> version 5

Here's one example that I ran into last night..

```
$response = $fb->get('/me/friends', $fbToken);
$fbfriends = $response->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
```

In the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/friends), if you look at the php example, they use getGraphObject. But when I use it, I get an error telling me I should probably use the Edge. There are a lot of "get" functions, but I don't see anything that tells me how to know what to use. getGraphObject, getGraphEdge, getGraphUser, etc. I'd love some insight into this one, because it's been a guessing game for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basicly, when:

- Getting `/{node-id}`, you should use `getGraphNode()` (`getGraphObject()` is deprecated)
- Getting `/{node-id-with-known-type}`, you should use `getGraph{Type}()`.
  For example, getting `/me` then use `getGraphUser()`, getting `/{event-id}` then use `getGraphEvent()`
- Getting `/{node-id}/{edge-name}`, you should use `getGraphEdge()` (`getGraphList()` is deprecated)
- Getting `/{node-id}/{edge-name-with-children-known-type}`, you should use `getGraphEdge({children-type-class})`.
  For example, getting `/me/albums` then use `getGraphEdge('GraphAlbum')`
  Nodes class name are in `Facebook\GraphNodes` namespace.

Comment: That's really helpful. Finding documentation on this specifically is a challenge with so much old depreciated documentation floating around out there.

Comment: This is very helpful even today. I can't even find where this is clearly explained in the PHP SDK docs. You would think FB would have better docs.

Comment: Facebook docs are famously horrendous. I remember the days of complaining about crappy Microsoft documentation with some longing.